# Animated Glow Effect for Button - C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, custom-controls

I want to apply animation to my button when pressing button. In WPF I can use `Storyboard` with triggers to create animation. Here is an example:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AniOpacityDelay">
  <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="background"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    AutoReverse="True"
    To="0.65"
    Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
</Storyboard>
```

and:

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
  Storyboard.TargetName="Itemcont"
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">

  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Windows Forms doesn't have `Storyboard` and triggers. How to make smooth animation in Windows Forms?

Here's my code for Windows Forms:

```
void DelayTime()
{
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = (int)System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.DelayTime).TotalMilliseconds;
  timer.Tick += (s, es) =>
  {
    this.mouseover = false; 
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    this.Enabled = true;
  };
  timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
  base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
  mouseover = true;
  this.Enabled = false;
  DelayTime();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Color bg = this._Background;
  bg = mouseover ? this._HoverColor : this._Background;
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bg), this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Comment: WinForms isn't really good at that.

Comment: For useless glitz do stay with WPF..

Comment: yeah, WPF is good. But the problem is I don't have a good computer .I may ask a new question about task and performance.@TaW @Maarten

Comment: It's not difficult to implement a smooth animated glow effect for button in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic idea is using a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and alpha-blending the glow color with original background color.

For example you can set [`FlatStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of the  button to `Flat` and override [`OnMouseEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseenter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [`OnMouseLeave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseleave?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). In `OnMouseEnter` start the timer and in and `OnMouseLeave` stop the timer. In timer `Tick` event you can set the [`MouseOverBackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance.mouseoverbackcolor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of [`FlatAppearance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatappearance?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of button to a color which you increase it's alpha channel in [`Tick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event.

[image: Glow Button]

**Glow Button Code**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class GlowButton : Button
{
    Timer timer;
    int alpha = 0;
    public Color GlowColor { get; set; }
    public GlowButton()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 50 };
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.GlowColor = Color.Gold;
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Gold;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = CalculateColor();
        timer.Start();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        timer.Stop();
        alpha = 0;
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = CalculateColor();
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int increament = 25;
        if (alpha + increament < 255) { alpha += increament; }
        else { timer.Stop(); alpha = 255; }
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = CalculateColor();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) timer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    private Color CalculateColor()
    {
        return AlphaBlend(Color.FromArgb(alpha, GlowColor), this.BackColor);
    }
    public Color AlphaBlend(Color A, Color B)
    {
        var r = (A.R * A.A / 255) + (B.R * B.A * (255 - A.A) / (255 * 255));
        var g = (A.G * A.A / 255) + (B.G * B.A * (255 - A.A) / (255 * 255));
        var b = (A.B * A.A / 255) + (B.B * B.A * (255 - A.A) / (255 * 255));
        var a = A.A + (B.A * (255 - A.A) / 255);
        return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I now using wpf.but wow.good idea. I need take note this.+2 if I can@Reza Aghaei

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) Yes, it's good, also you can apply this technique without setting style to flat, by turning off visual style back color and changing the `BackColor` using timer.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest you will get with winforms is probably making it DoubleBuffered. WinForms isn't very good for animations.

If you're using a custom control, add this under Initialize();

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Otherwise, make the form DoubleBuffered in the properties, or by code:

```
DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Then to create the animation(if you haven't already figured that out), do a loop checking if the animation is completed(in the timer event).

Comment: DoubleBuffered = true; on Form and DelayTime is eual 1.2 seem to be good.But still fast.@PaddiM8