# Create Custom Styled Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

I'm trying to create custom controls for my applications but it is not as easy as it seems... I just would like to create some custom flat-styled buttons that behave just like normal buttons, but with a completely different appearence (something like this):

[image: Flat Styled Button]

I've searched a lot about it, but I still can't handle that.
The type of button that I want to create is just like a normal button, I just want to inherit from the `Button` class in order to have the basic events and properties and change the appearence, but It's not very clear to me how to do that.

-Edit-

I also would like to manage the Hover effects, and being able to set properties such as the hover delay or hover color.

Anybody can help me to accomplish that?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think I've heard of people doing this, but I don't have any links handy.  FYI, if you have the choice between WinForms and WPF and it's early in the decision-making process, you might want to go with WPF, which makes this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: Set a Button's FlatStyle to Flat, then the BackColor to Green, ForeColor to White.

Comment: @LarsTech In this way I should do that for all the buttons I use... Also I could not create custom hover effects because the button would use the default ones.

Comment: Look at the FlatAppearance property, where you will find the MouseOverBackColor property, etc.

Comment: For a hver glow effect take a look at this post: [Animated Glow Effect for Button - C# Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049068/3110834)

Comment: Are you looking for a different feature than I shared in the linked post?