# Button Hover in usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I create a Usercontrol in form. the usercontrol contain Button, line and label. I want the button background turn to Blue when its being hovered and return to black when mouse leave. When I tried to run the outcome its not that i expected. when i hover, nothing happen but when I leave the background color turn to blue.

this my code inside the usercontrol:

```
    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Comment: [Animated Glow Effect for Button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049068/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void mEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    private void mLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Try using Mouse enter and mouse leave instead of mouse hover, mouse hover requires the mouse to actually be still above it. Enter just requires you to enter the bounds of the button.