# how do I customize my widgets or buttons borders and other advanced properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a bit new to winform and I dont know how to change stuff like widget borders or make smooth hover animations for buttons or other widgets, in css we do it like `transition: 1s;` but in C# I cannot find any property called `transition`, I'd appreciate if someone who knows what im talking about helps, thank you.

example: in this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEp4h.png) you can see that i've set my button's background color to purple but the border color hasn't changed.

Comment: You can set the [FlatStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to Flat, and then use [FlatAppearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to set the color. But for transition, there's no built-in support for in WinForms. You may find alternatives like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39049068/3110834), or use 3rd parties, or use a different framework which has built-in supports for this.

Comment: You might consider using WPF instead of Winforms.

Comment: @RezaAghaei which framwork would be the best to create modern GUIs?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp WPF would be able to do that?

Comment: [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: You'd better evaluate all available options and then choose cautiously, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea WinForms is old so might not be your best option.